# Can we extend the node type in a relay backend?

Tags: relayjs

the spec says that the Node type has only an ID field, but can we easily add a metadataobject to it? Will it be supported by the relay framework?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason it wouldn't work.

RelayJS requires you to have a Node interface, with an ID field on it, and that doesn't say anything about other fields.
I think you totally can.
You totally should.
Do it.

Just do it.

*This message was sponsored by Nike Programming